# Configurar o Apache2 com PHP 5.6 para usar o FuelPHP

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, ubuntu, framework

Bom vamos lá, eu utilizo *ubuntu*, *php5.6*, *apache2*, `mysql-server`, `FuelPHP`. E por enquanto estou utilizando o `xampp` que consegue rodar certinho minhas aplicações (porem tenho que iniciar ele sempre e ele não me deixa logar com mais de um usuário). Então eu quero começar usar o apache da maquina sem depender do `xampp`.

O problema é o seguinte, quando eu acesso meu sistema com `localhost/meuprojeto/public_html/` ele me joga para (`localhost/meuprojeto/public_html/users/login`) que seria a minha pagina de login correta porem da o seguinte erro:

> The requested URL /meuprojeto/public_html/users/login was not found on this server

Suspeito que o erro esteja em `apache2.conf`, que não está reconhecendo o `.htaccess` que fica dentro de `/meuprojeto/public_html/`. O `apache2.conf` se encontra da seguinte forma:

```
Directory

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied

/Directory

Directory /usr/share

    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

/Directory

Directory /var/www

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

/Directory
```

Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a achar o erro, ou me falar o possível erro.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema certamente está relacionado ao VirtualHost, que nada mais é que o responsável por redirecionar um determinado endereço para um local diferente do document root do localhost (explicando de maneira simples).

Sendo assim, ao invés de acessar direto pelo localhost sua aplicação, sempre crie um virtual host. Isso reduz a quantidade de problemas relativo a diretórios e redirecionamentos.

Portando basta fazer o seguinte: crie um virtual host para o endereço **fuelphp.local** (ou qualquer outro que você prefira):

```
# altere o fuelphp.local para o endereço que desejar
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName fuelphp.local
        ServerAlias fuelphp.local
        ServerAdmin seuemail@aqui.com.br
        DocumentRoot /var/www/meuprojeto/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/meuprojeto/public_html>
            Options Indexes Includes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
            Require all granted
            IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Observações

- Não esqueça adicionar o endereço que escolheu no seu arquivos hosts: `/etc/hosts` ou `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`.

  - Basta adicionar a seguinte linha no final do arquivo: `127.0.0.1    fuelphp.local` (ou qualquer outro endereço de sua escolha)
- Verifique se o `mod_rewrite` está habilitado no `apache.conf` (`/etc/apache2/apache.conf`), caso contrário os redirecionamentos não funcionarão corretamente.

  - Uma maneira de testar isso é criar um arquivo - `info.php` por exemplo - no document root do localhost, adicionar o seguinte código no arquivo: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` - e chamá-lo pelo navegador. Com isso você poderá pesquisar se a extensão existe ou não.

Comment: O `mod_rewrite` é do Apache, por que verificar nas configurações do php se ele está configurado?

Comment: @gmsantos perdão. Me confundi ao elaborar a resposta.